# Using lapply with make.names in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, r-factor

I am trying to convert all character columns in dataframe`df`into factors, each with valid R name levels, using`lapply`with`levels, factor`and`make.names`in its argument, as follows:

```
levels(df[, cols]) <- lapply(cols, function(x) make.names(levels(factor(df[, x]))))
```

`cols`is a vector of character column names. This is not working. If I only wanted to convert them to factors, without worrying about level names, the simpler syntax

```
df[, cols] <- lapply(cols, function(x) factor(df[, x]))
```

does work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a more complicated way of doing this than I hoped:

```
func <- function(x){
  df[, x] <- factor(df[, x])
  levels(df[, x]) <- make.names(levels(df[, x]))
  df[, x]
}
df[, cols] <- lapply(cols, func)
```